# Facebook Ads API Stats and "unique_impressions"

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, ads

When querying the stats for a campaign a value of "unique_impressions" is returned, is this equivalent to "Reach" as displayed in the Ad Manager on Facebook?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is: Yes. This was something that was answered in the PMD group on Facebook.

Comment: i need to integrate facebook ads api. please help me. please

Comment: Nathan Srivi: No offense, but your question is a bit on the vague side.  I would start here: http://bit.ly/1rWCvbn If that doesn't help feel free to send me a message and I'll try to help as much as I can.

Comment: thanks for your reply. are you integrate facebook ads api sdk or curl

Comment: i have a PMD account and i have a whitelisted app. what can i do next. when i install facebook ads sdk from github. many problem came. we install Composer, php unit and xdebug also but i got session error. please me any solution i am helpless. is there any other methods here.. like curl..????